# Classe estática de serviço em aplicação web

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos

Tenho uma classe para gerar relatório e outra para verificar e-mail em uma aplicação, deveria deixá-la como `static`? A classe de e-mail é para checar o e-mail em determinado período ou quando o usuário solicitar.

Comment: O lugar certo para isso é no programmers.

Comment: Deixar qual estática? A classe do reratório ou do e-mail?

Comment: @LucasHenrique eu não conheço esse forum, apenas o stackOverflow e o codeReview.

Comment: Ok :). http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @LucasHenrique, as duas por exemplo, minha pergunta é mais no sentido, de classes que vão ser acessadas a todo momento devem ser estáticas entende.

Comment: Eu sei que isso é ridículo, mas o que static faz? Me falaram que é diferente do static do C++.

Comment: Você não precisa instanciar uma classe para ter acesso a determinado método. Ou seja `Classe.metodoStatico`.

Comment: Ah, que bom, ao estilo C++ ;D.

Comment: @LucasHenrique Não tem programmers em português. A pergunta cabe aqui, mas poderia ser mais detalhada. Macario, você pode incluir mais detalhes sobre o a estrutura da sua app, e sobre os motivos da dúvida? Na forma atual, a pergunta dá muita margem a respostas opinativas, a aí fica difícil que uma seja "a correta". O ideal é você deixar a pergunta mais objetiva.

Comment: @bfavaretto Ele tem contas dos sites em inglês, acho que não tem problema.

Comment: @LucasHenrique se a pessoa veio perguntar em português, vamos ajudá-lo aqui. Dê uma lida no meta para conhecer melhor os objetivos deste site.

Comment: Tenho percebido que este é um dos problemas do `Stack`, sobre repetição de posts que já tem no site em inglês, mas eu fiquei realmente feliz com o fato de ver que há uma versão nacional deste fórum, e precisamos nós criar nossa base de dados também.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Classes estáticas", ou classes que contenham métodos estáticos de utilidade geral, são uma opção interessante para algumas tarefas comuns.

Pessoalmente, tenho o hábito de encapsular algumas rotinas dessa forma. Só para exemplificar:

```java
public class Texto {
    boolean vazia(String str) { return str != null && str.trim().length > 0; } 
    String primeiraMaiuscula(String str) { ... }
    String corta(String str, int limite) { ... }
    //....
}
```

Tais métodos podem ser importados estaticamente (`import static`) e usados em qualquer classe da aplicação web.

---

Por outro lado, para casos como sugerido na pergunta (relatórios e e-mails) não creio ser a melhor solução. Alguns motivos:

## Variação de uso gera confusão

Geração de relatórios e envio de e-mails podem ter parâmetros variados em funcionalidades diferentes na mesma aplicação. Com o tempo, isso acaba gerando um tipo de "biblioteca" cheia de métodos sobrecarregados. Vejamos um exemplo:

```java
public static void enviaEmail(String destinatario, String texto) { ... }
public static void enviaEmail(String destinatario, String conteudo, boolean html) { ... }
public static void enviaEmail(List<String> destinatarios, String texto) { ... }
public static void enviaEmail(List<String> destinatarios, String conteudo, boolean html) { ... }
public static void enviaEmail(List<String> destinatarios, String texto, File anexo) { ... }
public static void enviaEmail(List<String> destinatarios, String conteudo, boolean html, List<File> anexos) { ... }
```

Precisa continuar?

## Dependência de configuração ou valores externos

Quando uma rotina (método) depende de configurações (e-mail, local dos relatórios, etc.) seria melhor que a forma de recuperar os valores estáticos não fosse fixo.

Por exemplo, e se você cria as rotinas de envio de e-mails em métodos estáticos e depois descobre que precisa enviar e-mails usando mais de uma conta ou para mais servidores? Vai duplicar os métodos? Vai alterar configurações estáticas? Vai acrescentar mais parâmetros nos métodos existentes?

E para testar um método estático que carrega por si mesma uma certa configuração ou possui valores fixos? Quem trabalha seriamente com testes automatizados sabe que um método estático que faz muita coisa é "tiro no pé".

Enfim, métodos estáticos devem ter o mínimo de responsabilidade.

## E a economia em não instanciar classes?

Na prática, instanciar algumas classes não é o gargalo do sistema. Tanto no caso do envio de e-mails, quanto na geração de relatórios, a comunicação com o servidor SMTP, as consultas ao banco de dados e a criação do *output* (PDF, XLS, etc.) são os pontos onde se deve trabalhar para ganhar em desempenho.

Faça um investimento na arquitetura da sua aplicação e coloque tais rotinas em processos assíncronos capazes de criar logs informativos para as ações e repeti-las em caso de falha. Isso vai tornar sua aplicação mais responsiva (menor tempo de resposta) e menos dependente de otimizações desnecessárias.

Outro ponto muito importante é otimizar as *queries* dos relatórios, criando índices e usando técnicas eficientes de consulta (por exemplo, no SQL Server você pode acrescentar o *hint* `(NO LOCK)` nas queries de relatórios para evitar o tratamento de *locks*, que geralmente não importam muito quando apenas queremos listar os dados).

## Construindo objetos de forma inteligente

Finalmente, vou indicar algumas técnicas de como criar pequenas bibliotecas, das quais tenho gostado muito do resultado, e que estão descritas brevemente em meu artigo [**Construindo objetos de forma inteligente: Builder Pattern e Fluent Interfaces**](http://luizricardo.eti.br/2013/08/construindo-objetos-de-forma-inteligente-builder-pattern-e-fluent-interfaces/).

### Builder Pattern

Lembra da confusão das assinaturas estáticas para envio de e-mails? Uma forma de encapsular a criação de objetos com diferentes propriedades e atributos que nem sempre são usados é o padrão de projeto *Builder* (*Builder Pattern*).

Vamos usar o exemplo clássico da criação de uma Pizza, cuja abordagem simplista seria:

```java
public class Pizza {

    private int tamanho;
    private boolean queijo;
    private boolean tomate;
    private boolean bacon;

    Pizza(int tamanho) {
        this.tamanho = tamanho;
    }

    Pizza(int tamanho, boolean queijo) { 
        this(tamanho);
        this.queijo = queijo;
    }

    Pizza(int tamanho, boolean queijo, boolean tomate) {
        this(tamanho, queijo);
        this.tomate = tomate;
    }

    Pizza(int tamanho, boolean queijo, boolean tomate, boolean bacon) {
        this(tamanho, queijo, tomate);
        this.bacon = bacon;
    }

}
```

Imagine passar um parâmetro para cada ingrediente? Logo teríamos uma chamada assim:

```java
new Pizza(10, true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, ...)
```

Difícil e pouco intuitivo, né? Vamos então aplicar o *builder pattern*:

```java
public class Pizza {

    private int tamanho;
    private boolean queijo;
    private boolean tomate;
    private boolean bacon;

    public static class Builder {

        // requerido
        private final int tamanho;

        // opcional
        private boolean queijo = false;
        private boolean tomate = false;
        private boolean bacon = false;

        public Builder(int tamanho) {
            this.tamanho = tamanho;
        }

        public Builder queijo() {
            queijo = true;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder tomate() {
            tomate = true;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder bacon() {
            bacon = true;
            return this;
        }

        public Pizza build() {
            return new Pizza(this);
        }

    }

    private Pizza(Builder builder) {
        tamanho = builder.tamanho;
        queijo = builder.queijo;
        tomate = builder.tomate;
        bacon = builder.bacon;
    }

}
```

Agora podemos criar uma pizza vazia e cobri-la apenas com o que queremos:

```java
Pizza pizza = new Pizza.Builder(10)
                   .queijo()
                   .tomate()
                   .bacon()
                   .build();
```

Esta técnica é muito usada nos frameworks modernos, sendo meu exemplo predileto o [`ResponseBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.ResponseBuilder.html) da API JAX-RS.

### *Fluent Interfaces*

Outra forma muito legal para instanciação de objetos de bibliotecas é usar Interfaces  Fluentes. Com elas, podemos usar nossa criatividade e tornar a codificação mais flexível, mais direta e muito mais interessante.

Por exemplo, suponha que queremos criar um carrinho de compras. A primeira implementação simplista fica assim:

```java
public class Pedido {

    List<Item> itens;
    Cliente cliente;

    void adicionarItem(Item item) {
        itens.add(item);
    }

    void setCliente(Cliente cliente) {
        this.cliente = cliente;
    }

    void fechar() {
        // ...
    }

}
```

E o uso fica assim:

```java
Pedido p = new Pedido();
p.setCliente(new Cliente("José"));
p.adicionarItem(new Item("Motocicleta", 1));
p.adicionarItem(new Item("Capacete", 2));
p.fechar();
```

Aplicando o conceito de *fluent interfaces*, com poucas alterações, podemos deixar isso muito melhor:

```java
public class Pedido {

    List<Item> itens;
    Cliente cliente;

    Pedido com(int quantidade, String nome) {
        itens.add(new Item(nome, quantidade));
        return this;
    }

    Pedido para(String nome) {
        cliente = new Cliente(nome);
        return this;
    }

    void fechar() {
        // ...
    }

}
```

E então usamos o código assim:

```java
new Pedido()
    .para("José")
    .com(1, "Motocicleta")
    .com(2, "Capacete")
    .fechar();
```

O exemplo acima parece bem interessante se usado para envio de e-mails!

## Conclusão

Métodos estáticos são importantes e tem o seu lugar. Porém, não use esse recurso da linguagem se o objetivo for otimizar o código evitando a criação de instâncias de objetos. Também não use para casos de uso que não sejam triviais: quando há variação de argumentos, dependência de valores externos, risco de concorrência, etc.

Comment: na boa, parece que vc ta conversando com o código, muito doido, parece algo semelhante que preciso depois para estudar com mockito.

Answer (score 3):

Vai depender de como você utilizar essas classes. Mas, para isso, vamos por partes

### O que faz o static?

A palavra-chave `static` significa que, ao que ela se refere, pertence a classe e não a instância. Dessa forma, para utilizar métodos ou variáveis `static`, não será necessário instanciar um novo objeto daquela classe.

### Quando devo usar uma classe estática?

Como pode ser visto [nessa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7486111/1606920), não existe como você fazer um `static class`, mas, para criar uma classe estática, basta você tornar todas as variáveis e métodos estáticos.

Fazer uma classe estática, significa que ela não terá um comportamento diferente para cada objeto. Um exemplo de classe estática é a `Math`, cujo é desnecessário instanciar um objeto dessa classe, sendo que você só utilizará métodos de manipulação matemática e/ou constantes matemáticas.

Ou seja, uma classe deverá ser estática, quando todas as *possíveis* instâncias de objetos terão **sempre o mesmo comportamento**.

#### Resumindo

Uma classe estática é uma classe que teria um comportamento **igual** para **todos os objetos**, caso estes fossem instanciados.

Esse conceito deverá ser utilizado quando a sua classe não tiver um comportamento diferente, independente da quantidade de objetos que você instanciar. Cabe ao programador saber quando isso é uma realidade ou não.

Answer (score 1):

Você poderia ter seus métodos estáticos sem problema. Você poderia fazer algo como:

```
public final class EmailHelper {
    public static void enviarEmail(Usuario usuario, Relatorio relatorio){
        // seu código
    }
}
```

E outra classe para gerar o relatório:

```
public final class GerarRelatorio {
    public static Relatorio gerarRelatorio(...){
        // seu código
    }
}
```

Só tenha cuidado ao utilizar atributos de instância pois esse método será chamado por qualquer usuário do projeto. Por exemplo:

```
public final class EmailHelper {
    private String emailDoUsuario; // <--------- vai dar problema
    private String servidorDeEmail; // <-------- não vai dar problema

    public static void enviarEmail(Usuario usuario, Relatorio relatorio){
        // seu código
    }
}
```

Comment: na verdade minha idéia, é não ficar recriando aquele objeto que for acessado a todo momento entende?

Comment: Ops, foi mals. Faltou colocar o método como static. Já editei acima. [=

Answer (score 0):

Se você quiser, e é mais útil mesmo criar uma `interface` ou colocar os métodos e membros das duas classes (que você quer que sejam estáticas) dentro dos dois objetos de e-mail (que eu suponho que existam).